# OpenMP dependency and synchronization query

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

I have to parallelize a function in a serial numerical methods code on OpenMP. its structure is as follows;

```
int x = 0,y;
for(l=0;l <= 1 ;l++){
    y = 0;
    for(j = Xarr[l];j < Xarr[1+l];j++){
        y = y+1;
        x = x+1;
        a = func1(y,l);
        b = func2(y,l);
        for(i = 1; i < 400 ; i++){
            for(k = 1 ; k < 24 ; k ++){ 
                arr[k][i][j] = arr[k][i][j] + .other data.. ;
                arr1[k][**x**][j] = arr1[k][**x**][j] + .other data..; 
        }
     }
  }
}
```

on the RHS or `arr`, `arr1` the threads fetch data from other data.

I put pragma on 3rd and 4th inside "for" loops. However I am getting incorrect results when i put a `#pragma` omp parallel for collapse(2).

The dependency is for "x" and "y" actually. but unable to figure out.

Here "x" is not set to zero for every change in value of "l" (outermost for loop). That is causing the main problem.

If you can suggest any thing, please do so.

thanks!
Aditi.

Answer (score 0):

> x changes
>
> Just put **x = 0;** at the beginning of the loop (Outermost loop "**l**").                  The values (x and y) inside the inner loop (i and k) are to be shared by the all threads.

**The loop indices, need to be declared private or declared within for loop.**

The data along the arrays in c++ runs along the columns. Say you have a[i][j][k] then the next element along the memory is a[i][j][k+1]. The inner for loops (i and k) should be arranged accordingly.

Adding collapse() is usually used when both the indices are very small. **i*k = 400*24**, Say you have n thread, then one thread will do (i*k) work load and the n-1 thread will end up work-less.

If you can, try to put **j** as the most inner loop.

```
int x = 0,y;
for(l=0;l <= 1 ;l++)
{
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    for(j = Xarr[l];j < Xarr[1+l];j++)
    {
        y = y+1;
        x = x+1;
        a = func1(y,l);
        b = func2(y,l);
        #pragma omp parallel for shared(x, y, j, a, b) private(i, k)
        for(k = 1 ; k < 24 ; k++)
        {
            for(i = 1; i < 400 ; i++)
            { 
                arr[k][i][j] = arr[k][i][j] + .other data.. ;
                arr1[k][**x**][j] = arr1[k][**x**][j] + .other data..; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**I highly doubt that x = 0 is not set for each "l". Lets take a look the following code:**

```
int x, y;
for(int l = 0; l <= 5; l++)
{
    cout << "************************** L = "<< l << " ****************************\n";
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    for(int j = 0;j < 2;j++)
    {
        y = y+1;
        x = x+1;
        //  a = func1(y,l);
        //  b = func2(y,l);
        #pragma omp parallel for  shared(x, y, j)
        for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < 1 ; i++)
            { 
                #pragma omp critical
                {
                    cout << "tid:   " << omp_get_thread_num() << " out of " << omp_get_num_threads() <<  "| x:  " << x << " | y: " << y << endl;
                }
                //  arr[k][i][j] = arr[k][i][j] + .other data.. ;
                //  arr1[k][**x**][j] = arr1[k][**x**][j] + .other data..; 
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "***********************************************************\n";
}
```

Thing to note:

1. l: 0->5 so **six** total iteration of outer loop.
2. For each value of **l**, **j: 0->1** so **x** if is correctly set to **0**, then  maximum value of x would be: 2 for all iterations of **j**.
3. I have modified the indices length just have a visible output.
4. I run the code with 3 threads so I have **k:0->3** and for each k we print the value once with **i** for each thread.

I think the problem is somewhere else. Good Luck

The Output:

```
************************** L = 0 ****************************
tid:   0 out of 3| x:  1 | y: 1
tid:   1 out of 3| x:  1 | y: 1
tid:   2 out of 3| x:  1 | y: 1
tid:   2 out of 3| x:  2 | y: 2
tid:   1 out of 3| x:  2 | y: 2
tid:   0 out of 3| x:  2 | y: 2
***********************************************************
************************** L = 1 ****************************
tid:   2 out of 3| x:  1 | y: 1
tid:   1 out of 3| x:  1 | y: 1
tid:   0 out of 3| x:  1 | y: 1
tid:   2 out of 3| x:  2 | y: 2
tid:   1 out of 3| x:  2 | y: 2
tid:   0 out of 3| x:  2 | y: 2
***********************************************************
************************** L = 2 ****************************
tid:   2 out of 3| x:  1 | y: 1
tid:   1 out of 3| x:  1 | y: 1
tid:   0 out of 3| x:  1 | y: 1
tid:   1 out of 3| x:  2 | y: 2
tid:   2 out of 3| x:  2 | y: 2
tid:   0 out of 3| x:  2 | y: 2
***********************************************************
************************** L = 3 ****************************
tid:   2 out of 3| x:  1 | y: 1
tid:   1 out of 3| x:  1 | y: 1
tid:   0 out of 3| x:  1 | y: 1
tid:   2 out of 3| x:  2 | y: 2
tid:   1 out of 3| x:  2 | y: 2
tid:   0 out of 3| x:  2 | y: 2
***********************************************************
************************** L = 4 ****************************
tid:   2 out of 3| x:  1 | y: 1
tid:   1 out of 3| x:  1 | y: 1
tid:   0 out of 3| x:  1 | y: 1
tid:   2 out of 3| x:  2 | y: 2
tid:   1 out of 3| x:  2 | y: 2
tid:   0 out of 3| x:  2 | y: 2
***********************************************************
************************** L = 5 ****************************
tid:   2 out of 3| x:  1 | y: 1
tid:   1 out of 3| x:  1 | y: 1
tid:   0 out of 3| x:  1 | y: 1
tid:   2 out of 3| x:  2 | y: 2
tid:   1 out of 3| x:  2 | y: 2
tid:   0 out of 3| x:  2 | y: 2
***********************************************************
```

Comment: no luck with this. it failed in the correctness test. Note that here value of "x" is retained (not always set to zero) for every "l".